# Dynamic event handling - not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm having issues with dynamically handling the `MouseUp` event. Test code with issue:

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button2.MouseLeftButtonUp += something;
        }

        private void something(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
            Button2.MouseLeftButtonUp -= something;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want the `MessageBox` with the text "TEST" to show only the first time after I click `Button2`, after I've clicked `Button1`. It doesn't show up. The same code works with the `Click` event instead, but I need `MouseUp` to get the mouse position. I've confirmed that the first function fires, but the second doesn't no matter what I try. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Remarks section in [ButtonBase.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx):

> The ButtonBase marks the MouseLeftButtonDown event as handled in the
>   OnMouseLeftButtonDown method and raises the Click event. Hence, the
>   OnMouseLeftButtonDown event will never occur for a control that
>   inherits from ButtonBase. Instead, attach an event handler to the
>   PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event, or call AddHandler(RoutedEvent,
>   Delegate, Boolean) with handledEventsToo set to true.

Since `MouseLeftButtonDown` is handled internally, you will also get no 
`MouseLeftButtonUp` event. You could however use the [PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttonup.aspx) event instead.

Comment: +1 to that. If you really want to handle the bubbled event though, you can attach the handler in the code behind using UIElement.AddHandler method and specifying you want your handler to be invoked even if the event is already handled. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899.aspx

Comment: Yeah sorry :) Typed that a bit too quickly :)

Comment: Using the `PreviewLeftMouseButtonUp` worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Side note - How do I get a list of the attached Event Handlers?